# Insert data into Pandas DataFrame without index or column overhead (so not concat or append)

Tags: python, insert, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following example DataFrame:

```
In [227]: dfrm
Out[227]: 
          A         B         C  D           E
0  0.531428  0.045863  0.848619  1  2012-11-01
1  0.723965  0.508678  0.342828  2  2012-11-02
2  0.173907  0.962761  0.918959  2  2012-11-03
3  0.280061  0.067503  0.277317  1  2012-11-04
4  0.107908  0.949389  0.192078  1  2012-11-05
5  0.029907  0.240504  0.151579  1  2012-12-01
6  0.633516  0.217710  0.491811  2  2012-12-02
7  0.983545  0.450685  0.381446  1  2012-12-03
8  0.587426  0.833778  0.058891  2  2012-12-04
9  0.184342  0.664248  0.220923  1  2012-12-05

In [228]: dfrm.set_index(['E', 'D'])
Out[228]: 
                     A         B         C
E          D                              
2012-11-01 1  0.531428  0.045863  0.848619
2012-11-02 2  0.723965  0.508678  0.342828
2012-11-03 2  0.173907  0.962761  0.918959
2012-11-04 1  0.280061  0.067503  0.277317
2012-11-05 1  0.107908  0.949389  0.192078
2012-12-01 1  0.029907  0.240504  0.151579
2012-12-02 2  0.633516  0.217710  0.491811
2012-12-03 1  0.983545  0.450685  0.381446
2012-12-04 2  0.587426  0.833778  0.058891
2012-12-05 1  0.184342  0.664248  0.220923

In [229]: dfrm.set_index(['E', 'D']).A.unstack(level=1)
Out[229]: 
D                  1         2
E                             
2012-11-01  0.531428       NaN
2012-11-02       NaN  0.723965
2012-11-03       NaN  0.173907
2012-11-04  0.280061       NaN
2012-11-05  0.107908       NaN
2012-12-01  0.029907       NaN
2012-12-02       NaN  0.633516
2012-12-03  0.983545       NaN
2012-12-04       NaN  0.587426
2012-12-05  0.184342       NaN
```

Now, suppose that in this final example, I want to augment the DataFrame with a new row, which will be the first row.

I'll make up an index value for it, say `datetime.date(2012, 10, 30)` so that it just slightly pre-dates the existing first row. And I will just pass a list of two values, such as `[0.0, 0.0]` for the value for that first row.

How can I just append this structure to the top of the DataFrame **without** building a temporary structure that has the same column/index naming.

What I'm looking for in the output is:

```
D                  1         2
E           
2012-10-30  0.000000  0.000000          
2012-11-01  0.531428       NaN
2012-11-02       NaN  0.723965
2012-11-03       NaN  0.173907
2012-11-04  0.280061       NaN
2012-11-05  0.107908       NaN
2012-12-01  0.029907       NaN
2012-12-02       NaN  0.633516
2012-12-03  0.983545       NaN
2012-12-04       NaN  0.587426
2012-12-05  0.184342       NaN
```

**without** having to manually create a temp structure like this:

```
pandas.DataFrame({"E":[datetime.date(2012, 10, 30)], 
                    1:[0.0], 
                    2:[0.0]).set_index("E")
```

(and futzing around with the column-index's name "D") and then using `pandas.concat` or `DataFrame.append`).

I'm looking for something that just "inserts" whatever data -- only requiring that the tuple of values is of the right shape to have an index value and a value for each of the columns, and then it just pushes the data into those columns positionally.

In lots of searching, I couldn't find this functionality in pandas.

Supposing that it was called `insert_row` I'd be looking for some kind of interface that does this:

```
data_frame.insert_row((datetime.date(2012, 10, 30), 0.0, 0.0))
```

I could re-sort by the index to get it to the top, but the major point is that I want to provide a correctly-shaped `tuple` where the first element will be assumed the index and the rest assumed positional columns with no names or index structure needed.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way.  However, even if there were, the real overhead is that you cannot update the existing DataFrame in-place, so a new DataFrame must be created to hold the result.  The overhead of creating your small DataFrame to insert is probably small compared ot the overhead of creating the new large DataFrame to hold the result.

Comment: These are all small data frames. In my current application, the extra code required to make these nuisance temp structures with matching hierarchical and named columns is the problem. For very large data it might be worth it. But trying to parse the column name and hierarchy and auto-generate the insertable thing with matching index is unpleasant. `reindex_like` works some of the time, but enough corner cases exist that I thought to ask.

Comment: We'll see if anyone posts a solution.  However, I think that if you're doing things this way and hitting performance issues, it's worth considering alternative approaches to how you're generating your data structures.  Building up DataFrames by adding rows is fundamentally inefficient and there is often a smoother path.

Comment: It's not a performance issue -- rather a readability issue. It's for a demo where pre-populating certain rows prior to aggregating and plotting makes a lot of sense (and is common) for the problem domain. The data is never large enough that inserting rows and generating a new object would matter, but it makes the code vastly harder to read if you have to lace in all these calls to helper functions that try to understand the hierarchical indices and make the insertable data into a little DataFrame with matching indices/columns so that `concat` can work.

Comment: This is much more of a readability convenience need for small data demos than any performance need.

Comment: @BrenBarn is exactly right; much more efficient to append even small frames (or big ones too) to a list then concat all in 1 go. inserting is simply not efficient row-wise in a column based structure. that said what IS efficient is appending to a HDFStore which IS row based

Comment: It's not a question of efficiency. caring about that would amount to premature optimization in my problem. I am much more concerned that the stream of manipulations is very very very easy to read for people unfamiliar with much programming.

Comment: @EMS: In that case, could you just write your own helper function that does it?  So then your code would just look like `df = addRow(df, datetime.date(2012, 10, 30), 0.0, 0.0)`?  That would be pretty clear in code and you wouldn't have to delve into the details of how the row was added if it wasn't relevant.

Comment: Sure, but I thought it was worth it to ask before doing that. Especially since inside of that function, ugly parsing will need to happen of the indices. Whereas, I envision something at the `pandas` level ripping out the `data` attribute, doing a plain `numpy.vstack` of the data, calling the DataFrame constructor, and re-applying whatever index choices there were in the first place. Very much what `concat` must already do, except not forcing the user to pre-arrange for the indices to all make sense with each other other than positionally.

Comment: What's also frustrating is that is's very hard to make a new index from an existing one, as I am finding. Doing something like `dfrm.head(1)` is nice, but you cannot edit the index value there-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.ix[index] = row` to add row.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[4,5,6]}, index=list("xyz"))
df.ix["t"] = [10, 20]
```

I think it will copy the whole data, don't do this repeatly.